# solving the issue regarding running py2exe with numpy in my script

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, py2exe

Im trying to make an executable file using py2exe but it keeps giving me this: I've tried different versions of numpy py2exe , .. but it doesnt work.

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'ICCProfile', 'Numeric', 'PyQt4.QtGui', 'Pyrex.Compil  
er.Main', '__config__', '__svn_version__', '__umfpack', '_curses', '_imaging_gif
', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', '_transforms', 'builtins', 'compat.long', 'conf
igparser', 'copyreg', 'core.abs', 'core.max', 'core.min', 'core.round', 'csgraph
.cs_graph_components', 'fcompiler.FCompiler', 'genapi', 'gobject', 'mpl_toolkits
.natgrid', 'nose', 'nose.plugins', 'nose.plugins.base', 'nose.plugins.builtin',
'nose.plugins.errorclass', 'nose.plugins.manager', 'nose.util', 'numarray', 'num
py.CLIP', 'numpy.Inf', 'numpy.RAISE', 'numpy.WRAP', 'numpy.absolute', 'numpy.add
', 'numpy.all', 'numpy.allclose', 'numpy.amax', 'numpy.amin', 'numpy.any', 'nump
y.append', 'numpy.arange', 'numpy.arccos', 'numpy.arccosh', 'numpy.arcsin', 'num
py.arcsinh', 'numpy.arctan', 'numpy.arctan2', 'numpy.arctanh', 'numpy.argmin', '
numpy.argsort', 'numpy.around', 'numpy.array', 'numpy.array2string', 'numpy.arra
y_equal', 'numpy.array_equiv', 'numpy.array_repr', 'numpy.array_str', 'numpy.asa
nyarray', 'numpy.asarray', 'numpy.asarray_chkfinite', 'numpy.asfarray', 'numpy.a
smatrix', 'numpy.atleast_1d', 'numpy.bitwise_and', 'numpy.bitwise_or', 'numpy.bi
twise_xor', 'numpy.bool_', 'numpy.cast', 'numpy.ceil', 'numpy.choose', 'numpy.cl
ip', 'numpy.compat.asbytes', 'numpy.compat.asbytes_nested', 'numpy.compat.asstr'
, 'numpy.compat.basestring', 'numpy.compat.bytes', 'numpy.compat.integer_types',
 'numpy.compat.isfileobj', 'numpy.compat.long', 'numpy.compat.open_latin1', 'num
py.compat.unicode', 'numpy.concatenate', 'numpy.conj', 'numpy.conjugate', 'numpy
.convolve', 'numpy.core.Inf', 'numpy.core.absolute', 'numpy.core.add', 'numpy.co
re.all', 'numpy.core.amax', 'numpy.core.amin', 'numpy.core.any', 'numpy.core.ara
nge', 'numpy.core.around', 'numpy.core.array', 'numpy.core.asarray', 'numpy.core
.atleast_1d', 'numpy.core.atleast_2d', 'numpy.core.atleast_3d', 'numpy.core.bitw
ise_and', 'numpy.core.bitwise_or', 'numpy.core.bitwise_xor', 'numpy.core.broadca
st', 'numpy.core.cdouble', 'numpy.core.complexfloating', 'numpy.core.concatenate
', 'numpy.core.conjugate', 'numpy.core.csingle', 'numpy.core.divide', 'numpy.cor
e.dot', 'numpy.core.double', 'numpy.core.empty', 'numpy.core.empty_like', 'numpy
.core.equal', 'numpy.core.errstate', 'numpy.core.fastCopyAndTranspose', 'numpy.c
ore.finfo', 'numpy.core.float32', 'numpy.core.float64', 'numpy.core.float_', 'nu
mpy.core.geterrobj', 'numpy.core.greater', 'numpy.core.greater_equal', 'numpy.co
re.hstack', 'numpy.core.inexact', 'numpy.core.inf', 'numpy.core.intc', 'numpy.co
re.integer', 'numpy.core.invert', 'numpy.core.isfinite', 'numpy.core.isinf', 'nu
mpy.core.isnan', 'numpy.core.isscalar', 'numpy.core.left_shift', 'numpy.core.les
s', 'numpy.core.less_equal', 'numpy.core.linspace', 'numpy.core.longdouble', 'nu
mpy.core.maximum', 'numpy.core.multiply', 'numpy.core.ndarray', 'numpy.core.newa
xis', 'numpy.core.not_equal', 'numpy.core.number', 'numpy.core.power', 'numpy.co
re.product', 'numpy.core.ravel', 'numpy.core.remainder', 'numpy.core.reshape', '
numpy.core.right_shift', 'numpy.core.rollaxis', 'numpy.core.shape', 'numpy.core.
signbit', 'numpy.core.sin', 'numpy.core.single', 'numpy.core.size', 'numpy.core.
sqrt', 'numpy.core.subtract', 'numpy.core.sum', 'numpy.core.swapaxes', 'numpy.co
re.take', 'numpy.core.transpose', 'numpy.core.ufunc', 'numpy.core.vstack', 'nump
y.core.zeros', 'numpy.correlate', 'numpy.cos', 'numpy.cosh', 'numpy.deprecate',
'numpy.diag', 'numpy.diagonal', 'numpy.divide', 'numpy.dot', 'numpy.double', 'nu
mpy.dtype', 'numpy.e', 'numpy.empty', 'numpy.equal', 'numpy.exp', 'numpy.expand_
dims', 'numpy.extract', 'numpy.eye', 'numpy.fabs', 'numpy.fft.fft', 'numpy.fft.i
fft', 'numpy.finfo', 'numpy.flatnonzero', 'numpy.float64', 'numpy.floor', 'numpy
.floor_divide', 'numpy.fmod', 'numpy.fromstring', 'numpy.greater', 'numpy.greate
r_equal', 'numpy.histogramdd', 'numpy.hstack', 'numpy.hypot', 'numpy.imag', 'num
py.inexact', 'numpy.inf', 'numpy.info', 'numpy.infty', 'numpy.inner', 'numpy.int
32', 'numpy.integer', 'numpy.intp', 'numpy.invert', 'numpy.iscomplex', 'numpy.is
complexobj', 'numpy.isfinite', 'numpy.isinf', 'numpy.isnan', 'numpy.isscalar', '
numpy.issubdtype', 'numpy.kron', 'numpy.left_shift', 'numpy.less', 'numpy.less_e
qual', 'numpy.lexsort', 'numpy.lib.add_newdoc', 'numpy.lib.asfarray', 'numpy.lib
.i0', 'numpy.lib.imag', 'numpy.lib.iscomplexobj', 'numpy.lib.real', 'numpy.lib.t
riu', 'numpy.linalg.LinAlgError', 'numpy.linalg.eigvals', 'numpy.linalg.inv', 'n
umpy.linalg.lstsq', 'numpy.linalg.norm', 'numpy.log', 'numpy.log10', 'numpy.log2
', 'numpy.logical_and', 'numpy.logical_not', 'numpy.logical_or', 'numpy.logical_
xor', 'numpy.ma.MAError', 'numpy.ma.MaskedArray', 'numpy.ma.filled', 'numpy.ma.g
etdata', 'numpy.ma.getmaskarray', 'numpy.ma.make_mask_descr', 'numpy.ma.masked',
'numpy.ma.masked_array', 'numpy.ma.nomask', 'numpy.matrix', 'numpy.maximum', 'n
umpy.mgrid', 'numpy.minimum', 'numpy.multiply', 'numpy.nan', 'numpy.ndarray', 'n
umpy.negative', 'numpy.newaxis', 'numpy.nonzero', 'numpy.not_equal', 'numpy.numa
rray.get_numarray_include_dirs', 'numpy.ogrid', 'numpy.ones', 'numpy.outer', 'nu
mpy.pi', 'numpy.place', 'numpy.poly1d', 'numpy.power', 'numpy.prod', 'numpy.prod
uct', 'numpy.put', 'numpy.putmask', 'numpy.r_', 'numpy.random.rand', 'numpy.rand
om.randn', 'numpy.rank', 'numpy.ravel', 'numpy.real', 'numpy.recarray', 'numpy.r
emainder', 'numpy.resize', 'numpy.right_shift', 'numpy.rollaxis', 'numpy.savetxt
', 'numpy.searchsorted', 'numpy.seterr', 'numpy.shape', 'numpy.sign', 'numpy.sin
', 'numpy.single', 'numpy.sinh', 'numpy.size', 'numpy.sometrue', 'numpy.sort', '
numpy.source', 'numpy.sqrt', 'numpy.squeeze', 'numpy.subtract', 'numpy.sum', 'nu
mpy.swapaxes', 'numpy.take', 'numpy.tan', 'numpy.tanh', 'numpy.trace', 'numpy.tr
anspose', 'numpy.triu', 'numpy.true_divide', 'numpy.uint8', 'numpy.vdot', 'numpy
.vectorize', 'numpy.vstack', 'numpy.where', 'numpy.who', 'numpy.zeros', 'numpy_a
pi', 'numpy_distutils', 'numpy_distutils.command.build_flib', 'numpy_distutils.c
ommand.cpuinfo', 'numpy_distutils.cpuinfo', 'numpy_distutils.fcompiler', 'pkg_re
sources', 'pyemf', 'qt', 'scikits.umfpack', 'scipy._build_utils.get_g77_abi_wrap
pers', 'scipy.arange', 'scipy.linalg.LinAlgError', 'scipy.linalg._cblas', 'scipy
.linalg._clapack', 'scipy.linalg.get_blas_funcs', 'scipy.linalg.inv', 'scipy.lin
alg.lu_factor', 'scipy.linalg.lu_solve', 'scipy.linalg.norm', 'scipy.linalg.qr',
 'scipy.linalg.solve', 'scipy.linalg.solve_triangular', 'scipy.linalg.svd', 'sci
py.linalg.svdvals', 'scipy.misc.comb', 'scipy.ones', 'scipy.optimize.approx_fpri
me', 'scipy.optimize.curve_fit', 'scipy.sparse.SparseEfficiencyWarning', 'scipy.
sparse.coo_matrix', 'scipy.sparse.csc_matrix', 'scipy.sparse.csr_matrix', 'scipy
.sparse.eye', 'scipy.sparse.issparse', 'scipy.sparse.isspmatrix', 'scipy.sparse.
isspmatrix_csc', 'scipy.sparse.isspmatrix_csr', 'scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOpera
tor', 'scipy.sparse.linalg.aslinearoperator', 'scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres', 'scip
y.sparse.linalg.onenormest', 'scipy.sparse.linalg.splu', 'scipy.sparse.linalg.sp
solve', 'scipy.sparse.sparsetools.cs_graph_components', 'scipy.sparse.spdiags',
'scipy.sparse.speye', 'scipy.special.gammaln', 'setuptools', 'setuptools.command
', 'setuptools.command.bdist_rpm', 'setuptools.command.develop', 'setuptools.com
mand.egg_info', 'setuptools.command.install', 'setuptools.command.sdist', 'sitec
ustomize', 'sparsetools.bsr_matmat_pass2', 'sparsetools.bsr_matvec', 'sparsetool
s.bsr_matvecs', 'sparsetools.bsr_sort_indices', 'sparsetools.bsr_transpose', 'sp
arsetools.coo_matvec', 'sparsetools.coo_tocsr', 'sparsetools.coo_todense', 'spar
setools.csc_tocsr', 'sparsetools.csr_count_blocks', 'sparsetools.csr_matmat_pass
1', 'sparsetools.csr_sample_values', 'sparsetools.csr_tobsr', 'sparsetools.csr_t
ocsc', 'sparsetools.dia_matvec', 'sparsetools.get_csr_submatrix', 'testing.Teste
r', 'urllib.error', 'urllib.parse', 'urllib.request', 'usercustomize', 'win32api
', 'win32con', 'win32pdh', 'win32pipe', 'winreg', 'wx']
```

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

OLEAUT32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
   USER32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
   IMM32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
   ole32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
   COMDLG32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
   COMCTL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\COMCTL32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   msvcrt.dll - C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
   GDI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
   MSVCP90.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\MSVCP90.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
   KERNELBASE.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
   ntdll.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll

Comment: you should use cx_freeze instead of py2exe. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005533/creating-cx-freeze-exe-with-numpy-for-python

Comment: ive instaLled it but cant figure out how to run it?

Comment: I have no problem using `py2exe` with `numpy`. For some reason it doesn't seem to find one of the `dll`s, which you can fix by importing `numpy` in your setup script.