# How to add a hook for textblob in pyinstaller

Tags: hook, pyinstaller, textblob

I am trying to create a .exe file using pyinstaller and execute it 
it is not fetching any result from
`b = TextBlob(ar)
score = b.sentiment.polarity`

it returns proper value when executed on console
but return 0 when executed with .exe

```
def start_dmo():
 print ("Importing all the required packages...")
 from textblob import TextBlob
 input ("press enter to continue")
 print("All Necessary Packages imported")
 input("press enter to continue")
 ar="I cant be more happy with this"
 print(ar)
 b = TextBlob (ar)
 score = b.sentiment.polarity
 print (b.sentiment.polarity)
 input("press enter to continue")
 score = round (score, 2)
 if score > 0.0:
    senti = "Positive"
elif score < 0.0:
    senti = "Negative"
else:
    senti = "Neutral"
 print("Score"+str(score)+"sentiment"+senti)
 input("press enter to continue")

start_dmo()
```

[this is the output when the above code is executed on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S3YP.png)

[this is the output when the above code is executed on .exe of the same code which is created using pyinstaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1AVn.png)

Comment: @user772401 can you please help me out ?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved!
Simple Solution
Changed pyinstaller to cx_Freeze
FYI cx_Freeze works perfectly fine with python 3.6
to know how to create .exe using cx_freeze follow the below link:
https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-python-scripts-exe-executables/

if u use numpy or pandas u might need to add option cz it might not import numpy to form ur exe so solve that issue follow below link:
[Creating cx_Freeze exe with Numpy for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005533/creating-cx-freeze-exe-with-numpy-for-python)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller is not including `en-sentiment.xml` in the package, so the sentiment analyzer is missing a dependency and returns 0. Textblob doesn't produce an error in this case.

pyinstaller requires that you specify any data files in `myscript.spec` manually. However, as you've discovered, it appears that `cx_Freeze` honors the `setup.py` configuration, which specifies the data files to be included already:

```
package_data={
  "textblob.en": ["*.txt", "*.xml"]
}
```

To resolve, modify the pyinstaller `myscript.spec` file to copy `textblob/en/en-sentiment.xml`, or switch to `cx_Freeze` as discussed.

See my post on [Github](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/185) as well.

Comment: This resolved it for me. In my case the issue was intermittent, some texts would return scores, others wouldn't. After explicitly including the files it now works, not sure why some worked before including them however.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `textblob` before of your `start_dmo` function so that pyinstaller is aware of it as a dependency.

```
from textblob import TextBlob

start_dmo():
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

hey copy textblob from site packages to your working directory 
and run below in .spec

```
  a = Analysis(.....
         datas=[( 'textblob/en/*.txt', 'textblob/en' ),
     ( 'textblob/en/*.xml', 'textblob/en' )],
     ....)
```

it will work

Comment: Hello, what do you mean with "copy textblob from site packages"?