# error in creating executable file from python

Tags: python, winforms, numpy, pycharm, pyinstaller

i coded a python script in pycharm as "probe.py" and later built the executable(.exe) file out of it using the mentioned code in setup.py file but the exe file thus created shows error on opening as
import error mising required dependency['numpy'] even when it is present in my project.

**error image**

[image]

```
  import sys

  from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable


  include_files = ['autorun.inf']
  base = None

  if sys.platform == "win32":
  base = "Win32GUI"

  setup(name="Probe",version="0.1",description="fun",
  options={'build_exe':{'include_files': include_files}},
  executables=[Executable("probe.py",base=base)])
```

`

Comment: what is you error?  can you post that as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating cx\_Freeze exe with Numpy for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005533/creating-cx-freeze-exe-with-numpy-for-python)

Comment: @Nihal I added a picture as a description of the error dialog. Thanks!

Comment: Please, never post pictures unless it is a GUI issue, copy and paste the text of the error into your question.

Comment: how can you copy paste windows error popup message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
   base = None
   if sys.platform == "win32":
     base = "Win32GUI"
   build_exe_options = {"packages": ["numpy"],
     include_files = ['autorun.inf']}

   setup(
        name = "Probe",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "fun",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("probe.py",base=base)]
        )
```

run this script tell me if there is a problem

Comment: glad to help mate

Answer (score 0):

According to [cx_Freeze documentation](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html), try adding build_exe with a packages key.