# Creating executable file of my python script

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

I am trying to create an executable file out of my python script. 
System config :

```
python --version : 
                Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.
                conda : 4.3.16
                numpy : 1.14.3
                pandas : 0.23.4
                py2exe : 0.6.9
                pyinstaller : 3.4
                cx-Freeze : 5.1.1
```

**Method 1:** I tried `pyinstaller` but unfortunately it needs `PyQt5` and since `pyqt5` is not supported for `python 2.7` environment I couldn't proceed with this method https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files

**Method 2:** `py2exe` 
1) `python setup.py install`
2) `python setup.py py2exe`
but when I do run my exe file in `cmd` I get the following error

error:

```
X:\Data_Analytics\ETL\dist>Expiry.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Expiry.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "pandas\__init__.pyc", line 19, in <module>
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Setup code file :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

setup(console=['Expiry.py'])
```

**Method 3:** `cx_Freeze`
command: `python setup.py build`
setup file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

setup(name = "Expiry" , 
      version = "1.0" , 
      description = "" , 
      executables = [Executable("Expiry.py")])
```

Error:

```
X:\Data_Analytics\ETL\build\exe.win-amd64-2.7>Expiry.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "X:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "Expiry.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "X:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.23.4-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I have tried reinstalling `pandas` and `numpy` also, tried reinstalling anaconda but no luck.

Comment: try to add the packages you are using in py2exe setup options ?
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions

Comment: Check example in the page or https://www.pythoncentral.io/py2exe-python-to-exe-introduction/

Comment: for cx_freeze 
https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils-setup-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jpeg as pointed out, here is my solution that worked after your recommendation.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 
options = {'build_exe': {'packages': ['numpy'], 'include_files':['X:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\mkl_intel_thread.dll']} }

setup(name = "Expiry" , 
       version = "1.0" , 
       description = "" ,
       options = options,  
       executables = [Executable("Expiry.py")])
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You should be able to run the following commands without errors in a Python console:

   ```
   import numpy
   print numpy.__version__
   import pandas
   print pandas.__version__
   ```

   If this does not work, you first need to (re-)install `numpy` and `pandas` in this order.
2. In order to freeze a script depending on `pandas` (and thus on `numpy`) with `cx_Freeze`, you need to explicitly add `numpy` to the `packages` list of the `build_exe` options. Try with the following modification of your setup script:

   ```
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

    options = {'build_exe': {'packages': ['numpy']}}

    setup(name = "Expiry" , 
          version = "1.0" , 
          description = "" ,
          options = options,  
          executables = [Executable("Expiry.py")])
   ```

   See [Creating cx_Freeze exe with Numpy for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10005533/8516269).

Comment: it worked, exe got created but now i am facing new error: Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar This probably has to do with the way Anaconda handles packages. You probably need to explicitely tell `cx_Freeze` to include the DLL using the `build_exe` option `include_files`. Where is `mkl_intel_thread.dll`? (should be somwhere in `X:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ `)

Comment: i dont find this mkl_intel_thread.dll in my  X:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\  do i need to download and place in this directory, also this will be the changes right?   options = {'build_exe': {'packages': ['numpy'], 'include_files ':['X:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\mkl_intel_thread.dll']} }   i am bit naive to all this pls help