# Python exe file fails due to ModuleNotFoundError: Numpy. This is confusing because numpy is already installed and the program works in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, windows, numpy

I've written a Python program using pandas in Pycharm which works really well. However when I try to convert the Python program into an .exe file using pyinstaller in command prompt, the program fails. It successfully converts to an exe file but wehen I execute the program, a new window appears for 0.25 seconds and than terminates. I took a print screen of the window and the error it says is

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named numpy. "
```

This is really confusing as Numpy is installed and the program executes perfectly in pycharm. I've tried copying and pasting the code to a new file, and created a new python file with that code. Still getting the same issue. I'd appreciate any advice you can provide :)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53281867/creating-executable-file-of-my-python-script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316480/pyinstaller-with-pandas-and-numpy-exe-throws-error-at-runtime