# cx_Freeze not able to build msi with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cx-freeze

Hi I have following cx_Freeze `setup.py` file for an application that uses 
`pandas` module. When I generate `msi` I am facing issues. I looked all over the google for this but none of them are working for me.

```
include-files = ['aardvark.dll'] 
includes = []
excludes = []

base = "Win32GUI"
exe = Executable( 
    script="test.py",
    initScript=None,
    base=base,
    targetName="test.exe",
    copyDependentFiles=True,
    compress=False,
    appendScriptToExe=False,
    appendScriptToLibrary=False,
    shortcutDir="MyProgramMenu",
    shortcutName=APP_NAME)
bdist_msi_options = {
    "upgrade_code": UPGRADE_CODE,
    "add_to_path" : False}
setup( 
    name=APP_NAME,  
    version=VERSION,
    author="sri",
    description='test Tool',
    options={"build_exe": {"excludes":excludes,
    "includes":includes,
    "include_files":includefiles},
    "bdist_msi" : bdist_msi_option},
    executables=[exe])
```

When I build `msi` with `cx_Freeze==4.3.4` it gives 
this error:

> cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no file named sys (for module collections.sys)

and when I use `cx_Freeze >= 5.0.0` the `msi` is created but after installing this gives

> ImportError: Missing required dependencies['numpy']

[image]

I tried all the available stack overflow work around but none of them is working any suggestion will be a great help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` depends on `numpy` and you need to explicitly add `numpy` to the `packages` list of the `build_exe` options in order that `cx_Freeze`includes `numpy`correctly, see [Creating cx_Freeze exe with Numpy for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10005533/8516269)

Try to add the following to your setup script

```
packages = ['numpy']
```

and to modify the `options` according to

```
options={"build_exe": {"excludes":excludes,
                       "includes":includes,
                       "include_files":includefiles,
                       "packages":packages},
         "bdist_msi" : bdist_msi_option},
```

Comment: Hi @jpeg,I tried what  you said, still getting the  same ImportError: missing required dependencies['numpy'] after running the application.

Comment: Hi @jpeg thanks for the solution packages=['numpy'] worked, the problem was i did not reboot the system after changing different versions of cx_Freeze.